# How do I create a Rails model in a different DB schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3.2 app backed by MS SQL 2008. All its models are by default created in `dbo` schema. Now I want to have a model which DB table has limited access to it so I want to put it to a different DB schema. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just define it together with table name:

```
def change
  create_table "schema_name.table_name" do |t|
    #init table
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add *schema_search_path: 'schema1,schema2'* to the database.yml.